# How can I Allow my Chrome App to access external Api

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, external

I'm fresh out of college and trying new things. I'm attempting to make a chrome app and want to use:

```
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
```

When I try to run it I get this error:

```
Refused to load the script 'http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I read up on CSP and the like but I cant seem to get it to work.

I have tried throwing a content_security_policy into my manifest but still no luck. Maybe I'm doing it wrong:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://connect.soundcloud.com/; object-src 'self'"
```

Any help would be super amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to connect with an API and to do this, you need to edit the permissions in the app's manifest file. See: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings

If you want to load external content from another website, you need to isolate it. See https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external

Comment: I remember coming across those. I tried following the instructions but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest.json, you'll need to specify a custom Content Security Policy. In particular, for your example, you'll need to specify:

```
"content_security_policy": "... script-src: http://connect.soundcloud.com/ ..."
```

This will add connect.soundcloud.com to the whitelist of locations that your app is allowed to load scripts from. This is to help prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks against your app.

For more information about how CSP is applied to Chrome Apps, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy. For a more general overview of the very cool Content Security Policy technology, see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/.

Comment: I have tried doing that but still no luck, I have updated my topic with more details on what my CSP looks like.

Comment: Outright wrong answer, you are looking a the wrong docs. Chrome Apps CSP docs are here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy It specifically mentions that unlike extensions, you _cannot_ override CSP for apps.